# Scaled tick option not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot some time series data using `pgfplots`. I do not want any "tick scaling" (i.e. scientific notation for my axis). I have tried the `scaled ticks`and `scaled y ticks` options, setting them to `false`. However, this still produces

[image: Problematic axis]

I would like it to say `-0,05` and `0,05`.

Here's my example code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
       use comma}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid = both, date coordinates in = x,
    scaled ticks = false,
    no marks,
    xticklabel={\year},
    xlabel = {Year},
    ylabel = {Log-Return},
    ytick = {-0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1},
    ]
    \addplot[color = red] coordinates {
(2008-10-02,-0.0254135424025996)
(2008-10-03,0.0238105075745132)
(2008-10-06,-0.0733552237671908)
(2008-10-07,-0.011271710502907)
(2008-10-08,-0.0605605136703957)
(2008-10-09,-0.0255796141182998)
(2008-10-10,-0.072702704381916)
(2008-10-13,0.107974680453472)
(2008-10-14,0.0266522385158314)
(2008-10-15,-0.0671290843134731)
(2008-10-16,-0.0503709904911815)
(2008-10-17,0.0337160087215764)
(2008-10-20,0.0111643819661129)
(2008-10-21,-0.0105204008353059)
(2008-10-22,-0.0456154732581222)
(2008-10-23,-0.0113016115605298)
(2008-10-24,-0.0508381426486686)
(2008-10-27,0.00903107295142114)
(2008-10-28,0.10685088667814)
(2008-10-29,-0.003064794603306)
};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scaled ticks` will put a comman scale at the end of the axis. You need `fixed` number formatting option.

Use `fixed` in

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,
      use comma}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,
       use comma}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid = both, date coordinates in = x,
    scaled ticks = false,
    no marks,
    xticklabel={\year},
    xlabel = {Year},
    ylabel = {Log-Return},
    ytick = {-0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1},
    ]
    \addplot[color = red] coordinates {
(2008-10-02,-0.0254135424025996)
(2008-10-03,0.0238105075745132)
(2008-10-06,-0.0733552237671908)
(2008-10-07,-0.011271710502907)
(2008-10-08,-0.0605605136703957)
(2008-10-09,-0.0255796141182998)
(2008-10-10,-0.072702704381916)
(2008-10-13,0.107974680453472)
(2008-10-14,0.0266522385158314)
(2008-10-15,-0.0671290843134731)
(2008-10-16,-0.0503709904911815)
(2008-10-17,0.0337160087215764)
(2008-10-20,0.0111643819661129)
(2008-10-21,-0.0105204008353059)
(2008-10-22,-0.0456154732581222)
(2008-10-23,-0.0113016115605298)
(2008-10-24,-0.0508381426486686)
(2008-10-27,0.00903107295142114)
(2008-10-28,0.10685088667814)
(2008-10-29,-0.003064794603306)
};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]